# How to highlight (hover) two cells to change their background

Tags: html, css

I have 4 cells in a row. And I want to when I hover on first or second cell, the first and second cells change their backgrounds.
So I hover on first cell, first and second cells change background.
I hover on second cell, first and second cells change background.
I want to highlight two cells at a time.
Thanks, sure I explained my matter well. I am not :) that good in English.

Comment: Javascript is required to do it. What have you tried?

Comment: @nicael I have tried adding some classes, but nothing works. Please, help me

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: you've tried CSS hover?
`a:hover { 
    background-color: yellow;
}`

Comment: @RyanRebo I need to hover 2 cells at once

Comment: HTMLcode: <table>
   <tr>
    <td id="td1"></td>
    <td id="td2"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

Comment: CSS code: #td1:hover, #td2: hover
   {
    background-color: #317EAC
   }

Comment: @RyanRebo In first cell there is image, in the second one text. And I want to highlight image and text at once

Comment: Sounds like you need to group/nest some divs. Than target them by `div + div`. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp

Comment: @RyanRebo Looks like that is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example of using hover on table cells.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

table tr:first-of-type td:nth-child(1):hover, table tr:first-of-type td:nth-child(1):hover + td:nth-child(2) {
    background: green;
}

table tr:first-of-type td:nth-child(1):hover, table tr:first-of-type td:nth-child(1):hover + td:nth-child(2) {
    background: green;
}

table tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-child(1):hover, table tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-child(1):hover ~ td:nth-child(3) {
    background: green;
}
```

**Demo:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/9zxeLnhn/)

Comment: thanks a lot, but can how can split their background. When  I hover over the first cell and it changes background, I want first and second background turn green without any spaces

Comment: If you look at the CSS, you'll see that the first row has different CSS rules than the second row. If you only want the first and second cells to "highlight" when the first cell is hovered, you'll want to use this:

`table tr td:nth-child(1):hover, table tr td:nth-child(1):hover + td:nth-child(2){ background: green; }`